# Clarifai-node-js api import error while using it reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, jsx, clarifai

[image: import]

and

[image: error]

Hi. I attach 2 pictures. **There I am having an issue while importing Clarifai-nodejs-grpc.**
Please check these pictures and help me with this.
**Thank you so much**

Comment: Can you please write your Node.js version?

Comment: Node.js version is v16.15.1

Comment: this is what they said to use

const { ClarifaiStub, grpc } = require("clarifai-nodejs-grpc");

but I did 

 import { ClarifaiStub, grpc } from "clarifai-nodejs-grpc"; 

is that wrong?

Comment: Can you try reading this comment in the repo https://github.com/Clarifai/clarifai-nodejs-grpc/issues/25#issuecomment-1049779789 ?

Comment: you code seems to be fine, it's just an issue with the package, in the repo, this issue https://github.com/Clarifai/clarifai-nodejs-grpc/issues/25 says it happened for windows users.

Comment: Thank you so much, bro. I didn't notice that.
Thanks alot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- It seems like this issue has been reported here already: https://github.com/Clarifai/clarifai-nodejs-grpc/issues/25
- While I get someone to take on look on Clarifai's end, please use simple REST calls: https://docs.clarifai.com/api-guide/data/create-get-update-delete (see "Javascript (REST) snippet")

Comment: Hii there. Thank you for your comments. Actually, I didn't understand REST calls. As you can see I am using building it on React site. It will be really helpful if you please write the code or what should I use so that it won't show an Error.
Thank You